# Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android - "my friends" request never returns

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I've started making the upgrade to Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android. I've managed to open an active session (using the `Session.openActiveSession(...)` method) and get the current user's info (using the `Request.executeMeRequestAsync(...)` method). However! When I try to get the current user's list of friends as follows...

```
Request.newMyFriendsRequest(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    new Request.GraphUserListCallback()
    {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response)
      {
        // never called
      }
    });
```

... the `onCompleted(...)` callback is never called and my user is left hanging, forever. I've checked and my access token is valid and I'm [pretty sure](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends) no extra permissions are needed to get the current user's list of friends. Any ideas anybody? I'm stuck and Facebook developers bug-reporting is disabled!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling Request.newMyFriendsRequest just creates the request, it doesn't execute it.

You need to do something like:

```
Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(...);
request.executeAsync();
```

or just

```
Request.newMyFriendsRequest(...).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Yup, my bad, didn't realise there were two methods - `Request.newMyFriendsRequest(...)` and `Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsnc(...)`. Thanks Ming Li. Appreciate it.